# update-grub always removing windows EFI entry

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

My laptop (Vaio SVS1312C5E) always seems to start the Microsoft/... entry in the EFI partition if it exists. I can make ubuntu boot by mounting the EFI partition and renaming the Microsoft/ folder to something else.
If renamed to something else, then update-grub will not find the os and always remove the entry for windows from the boot list.

If I let grub-update run when Microsoft/ is present, it will correctly detect it and create an entry for it. I can then manually edit grub.cfg to point to the renamed folder e.g. MicroS and then rename Microsoft to MicroS to get it working.

However: update-grub is always run by ubuntu after a kernel has been added/removed. Therefore update-grub is regularly removing that entry, leaving my unable to boot to windows.

What can I do to prevent this from happening? Thanks a lot.

Comment: -1 for "_I can then manually edit grub.cfg_"

Comment: Avinash: Come on. The guy's found an inadequate workaround and is asking for help. Dinging him for what he implicitly acknowledges is an inadequate workaround is unreasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three suggestions:

- **Abandon GRUB 2** -- [Several other EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) are available, and when you start running into GRUB 2 problems, these alternatives are likely to be easier to configure than GRUB 2, which is complex and finicky. Chances are either [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or [Fedora's patched GRUB Legacy](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/grub_legacy.html) will work best, although with some adjustments to your configuration, [gummiboot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot/) might work well, too. Note that you may need to move the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` file down one level in its directory tree, to `EFI/Microsoft/bootmgfw.efi`, to get this to work with rEFInd; or create a manual boot stanza for Windows.
- **Run Boot Repair** -- The [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool includes the ability to rename boot loaders in a way that should fix your problem. If it works well, this may be easier than the first solution; but it's a little less elegant, and on occasion it causes additional problems.
- **Create a manual boot stanza** -- You can edit the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file to include the boot stanza that works with your renamed Windows file. GRUB should then pick it up. Overall, this is likely to be the quickest solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution 3 worked perfectly :) I had already tried the other above two solutions, but had no luck. I installed reFINd, but GRUB always booted. Since removing GRUB entirely would leave me unable to boot linux, this did not work. As for running boot-repair: I tried it with many different options, but it almost complained that my linux partition is too far at the back and did not fix anything. Again, thank you so much.